# Une majorité de Québécois entend bien garder l'habitude de porter le masque

Tags: articles

*C'est officiel : le masque ne sera plus obligatoire à partir du 14 mai*, Piere-Paul Biron dans *24 heures* :

> S'il faut croire un sondage de l'INSPQ paru mardi, **une** majorité de
> Québécois entend bien garder l'habitude de porter le masque même après
> le 14 mai.

Pourquoi l'auteur emploie l'article indéfini devant *majorité* et non l'article défini ? J'aurais écrit *la majorité des Québécois*.

J'ai lu ce [fil](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/8942/what-is-the-meaning-of-la-une-majorit%C3%A9-with-de-or-des), mais je ne comprends pas toujours pourquoi l'auteur utilise l'article indéfini dans cette phrase.

Answer (score 4):

"Une majorité" et "la majorité" peuvent vouloir dire la même chose.
Il faut savoir sur quel groupe dans la phrase nous voulons insister le plus.

C'est donc une histoire de sens de la phrase.

"La majorité de Québécois entend bien garder l'habitude de porter le masque" (on insiste sur la majorité) ;
"Une majorité de Québécois entend bien garder l'habitude de porter le masque" (on insiste sur les Québecois.)

Il s'agit pour l'auteur ici de certainement mettre en lumière cette partie de la population.